# Loop through store to validate column in grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridview, extjs5, extjs-stores

How can i loop through my store in a grid to validate a whole column? I know how to query the grid and store but how do i loop in it to check if that specific column has what I'm checking for?

```
var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridItemID')[0]; //query grid
grid.getStore().data.items[0].raw['HeaderOfColumnIWant']; //get column header
//now how to loop in store to validate what is in that column
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var me = this;
store.each(function(rec){
   if(rec.get('age') > 18){
     me.drinkBeer();
   }
});
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-each

also consider the renderer configuration if you want something like changing the way the cell looks if for example the the value of the field (of that column) < 0 and there is no need to iterate the store

```
renderer: function(value){
        if (value < 1) {
            return '<span style="color: red;">' + value + '</span>';
        }
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code helps.

```
var row, store = grid.getStore();
var count = store.getTotalCount();
for (var i=0;i<count;i++)
{
   rec = store.getAt(i);
   // Returns column value
   rec.get('HeaderOfColumnIWant')
}
```

**Note:** iterating through items and raw propety is not ideal.

Comment: close, but i get Cannot read property 'get' of null on the for loop.